# How to get TabItem ID Programmatically in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I have defined ids for all the TabItem inside a TabLayout in XML but I could not get the ids programmatically. **I know I achieve the same by using position parameter but I don't need that**. Any help is appreciated.

XML

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/unselected_tab">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/live_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Live" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/upcoming_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upcoming" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Kotlin:

```
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            when (tab.id) { //tab.id is not available
                R.id.live_tab -> showFragment(LiveFragment())
                R.id.upcoming_tab -> showFragment(UpcomingFragment())
            }
        }
```

**Update:**
According to  Mike M, Tabs don't have IDs. The id attributes you've specified in the layout are ignored. TabItem only supports text, icon, layout, and contentDescription. Hope this might help some one.

Comment: `Tab`s don't have IDs. The `id` attributes you've specified in the layout are ignored. `TabItem` only supports `text`, `icon`, `layout`, and `contentDescription`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Tabs don't have IDs. The id attributes you've specified in the layout are ignored. TabItem only supports text, icon, layout, and contentDescription.

@Sai & @MikeM. is right. `TabLayout.Tab`'s don't have IDs.

But, let me introduce a possible workaround. We are going to use `contentDescription` as our identifiers.

Create a resource file in `res/values/` with any name (say `tab_identifiers.xml`) and add some identifiers in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- MEDIA PAGE TABS -->
    <string name="tab_import_media">ImportMedia</string>
    <string name="tab_play_media">PlayMedia</string>
    <string name="tab_mux_media">Muxer</string>
</resources>
```

You can use real content description as well, after all this file is just a string resource keeper.

Now, in your Activity/Fragment XML, add these strings as `contentDescription`s like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/media_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tab_import_media"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tab_play_media"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tab_mux_media"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Now, you can identify all `TabItem`'s easily through `contentDescription`s. In your `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener#onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab)`, do something like this:

```
override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    Log.d("MediaFragment", "selectedTab = ${tab?.contentDescription}")
}
```

Obviously, this is kind-of a hack. But it works, and it seems to survive process death as well.